# What's the difference between Celery task and subtask?

Tags: python, celery

If I understood the tutorial correctly, Celery *subtask* supports almost the same API as *task*, but has the additional advantage that it can be passed around to other functions or processes.

Clearly, if that was the case, Celery would have simply replaced *tasks* with *subtasks* instead of keeping both (e.g., the `@app.task` decorator would have converted a function to a *subtask* instead of to a *task*, etc.). So I must be misunderstanding something.

What can a *task* do that a *subtask* can't?

Celery API changed quite a bit; my question is specific to version 3.1 (currently, the latest).

Edit:

I know the docs say *subtasks* are intended to be called from other *tasks*. My question is what prevents Celery from getting rid of tasks completely and using subtasks everywhere? They seem to be strictly more flexible/powerful than tasks:

```
# tasks.py
from celery import Celery
app = Celery(backend='rpc://')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    # just print out a log line for testing purposes
    print(x, y)

# client.py
from tasks import add
add_subtask = add.subtask()
# in this context, it seems the following two lines do the same thing
add.delay(2, 2)
add_subtask.delay(2, 2)
# when we need to pass argument to other tasks, we must use add_subtask
# so it seems add_subtask is strictly better than add
```

Comment: I think subtasks are secondary tasks run from a task. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349371/celery-task-that-runs-more-tasks

Comment: @Hussain Yes, precisely. See my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

You will take the difference into account when you start using [complex workflows](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html) with celery.

> A signature() wraps the arguments, keyword arguments, and execution
>   options of a single task invocation in a way such that it can be
>   passed to functions or even serialized and sent across the wire.
>
> Signatures are often nicknamed “subtasks” because they describe a task
>   to be called within a task.

Also:

> subtask‘s are objects used to pass around the signature of a task
>   invocation, (for example to send it over the network)

`Task` is just a function definition wrapped with decorator, but `subtask` is a task with parameters passed, but not yet started. You may transfer the subtask serialized over network or, more used, call it within a group/chain/chord.

Comment: Hmm, that is clear, but I somehow still don't understand the answer to my original question: aren't subtasks strictly more powerful/flexible than tasks? Why even bother having tasks, why not remove that concept from Celery, and only deal with subtasks? Unlike tasks, subtasks can be passed around, can be partialized, can be combined in complex workflow.  And yet, subtasks also have `.delay()` method just like tasks. Is there anything that a task can do that subtask can't?

Comment: As far I understand it - yes, subtasks looks more flexible because they allow to organize workflows. But if you do not use complex 'canvas' workflows - you may use just tasks. Task is a more high-level abstraction than subtasks. Subtask is nothing but a serialized task.

Comment: How is task a higher-level abstraction?.. Based on my understanding, and on your answer, *task* can do a tiny fraction of what *subtask* can do, and can do nothing that *subtask* can't... Why would I want to use a crippled object, when the much more powerful object is just as easy to use?

Comment: First of all, I guess `task` historically comes first rather than `subtask`. Then, `subtask` is just an alias to `signature` as we can see from the code. They have different goals.
`task` is a class implementing functions to manage execution process. `subtask` is this class technically wrapped to `dict`-like object. When you use decorator `@task` for a function - you receive an object instead. And it just implements method `subtask`.
You *can* use any of these approaches, but in celery they are different entities.

Comment: History: understood; but are you implying *subtask* isn't backward compatible with *task*? How so? The API seems the same, what am I missing?

Comment: The same API does not mean the same objects. Subtask is just a packed task.

Comment: The Celery nomenclature is inconsistent and obfuscated.  So-called "subtasks" can be called directly (not just from within tasks), and tasks can be called from within tasks without using signatures at all.  It's a friggin mess.